# JWPLAYER - HOW NOT TO SHOW PLAYER WHEN NO RTMP CONNECTION

Tags: wordpress, jwplayer, rtmp, jwplayer7

I would like to know how to 'not show' my jwplayer when noactive rtmp connections. I have a page setup in wordpress but only want to show active video player(s) when they come online?

Answer (score 1):

For jwplayer 6 you can use `jwplayer().onError` to check if stream is not active, and show an image/video/text error message to user. You can add `setTimeout()` to try every x seconds to reload page. 
You can also manipulate your DOM inside `jwplayer().onError` to hide player or show another div with a message.